# Command line arguments in swift - convert to interger

Tags: swift

Want achieve in `swift` (MacOS) the following dead-simple `perl` script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
for my $arg (@ARGV) {               #loop over arguments
    next if $arg !~ /^\d+$/;        #skip if not all digits
    print("arg:", $arg + 2, "\n");  #print the number + 2...
}
```

so invoking this script as: `perl script.pl 10 20 30` prints

```
arg:12
arg:22
arg:32
```

My "experiment" in `swift` script called `arg.swift`:

```swift
import Darwin // otherwise the "exit" won't works...

if CommandLine.argc < 2 {
    print("Error", CommandLine.arguments[0], " No arguments are passed.")
    exit(1)
}
    
for i in 1 ..< CommandLine.argc {   // in the "0" is the program name (as above) so skip it
    print("arg:", CommandLine.arguments[i] + 2) // add 2 and print the result
}
```

running it as `swift arg.swift 10 20 30` , prints the following errors..

```
arg.swift:9:44: error: cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'Int32'
        print("arg:", CommandLine.arguments[i] + 2)     // add 2 and print the result
                                           ^
arg.swift:9:44: note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int), (Range<Int>), (Range<Self.Index>), ((UnboundedRange_) -> ())
        print("arg:", CommandLine.arguments[i] + 2)     // add 2 and print the result
```

Honestly, absolutely don't understand what is wrong, so why `CommandLine.arguments[0]` works, and it complains about `CommandLine.arguments[i]`... Also, what(?) about `overloads`?

if someone needs, using:

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arguments are passed as `String`s, so if you want to use them as `Int`s, you need to add the conversion.

Also, `argc` is an UInt32 and needs to be converted as well so that you can use it as a subscript index.

For example, like so:

```
for i in 1 ..< Int(CommandLine.argc) {
  if let intValue = Int(CommandLine.arguments[i]) {
    print("arg:", intValue + 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: YES! The `Int(CommandLine.argc)` is crucial. Thanx. :)